# How do you round an average in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, average, rounding

I'm displaying star ratings based on a review, using conditionals like the following:

```
- if page.page_reviews.average('rating') == 5
  %p Do something...
```

The problem is... with a 1-5 review system, not all averages equate to whole numbers. How can I round each average to the nearest whole number in Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Ruby's Float#round

Without arguments, the [Float#round](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html#method-i-round) method will convert a Float to the nearest Integer. For example:

```
(2.5).round
#=> 3

avg = 3.2
avg.round
#=> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
2.0.0-p247 :002 > (1.2).ceil
 => 2
2.0.0-p247 :003 > (1.2).floor
 => 1
2.0.0-p247 :004 > (1.2).round
 => 1
2.0.0-p247 :005 > (1.8).round
 => 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Math.floor(number + 0.5)
```

to round the nearest integer value (4.7 rounds to 5). Do not include the addition of 0.5 if you just want to round to the integer part of the value (e.g. 4.7 rounds to 4).